# why the sequence $ \{q_n \} $ converges to $ + \infty $?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $ \alpha \notin \mathbb {Q} $. We know that (according to Liouiville's approximation) for any strictly positive integer $ n $, there exists a strictly positive integer $ p_n $ and an integer $ q_n $ such that
$$
| \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n} | <\frac {1} {q_n^2}
$$
My problem is why the sequence $ \{q_n \} $ converges to $ + \infty $?

Comment: The hypotheses allow one to choose $p_n = p$ and $q_n = p$ independent of $n$? In this case the convergence doesn't hold.

Comment: But I read this in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042356/approximate-irrational-numbers-with-the-same-denominator

Comment: That post says that there is a sequence $q_n \to +\infty$ such that (for suitable $p_n$) we have $\bigl\lvert \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n}\bigr\rvert < \frac{1}{q_n^2}$. Not that $q_n \to +\infty$ holds for all such sequences. But $q_n \to +\infty$ holds for all sequences of positive integers that attain each value only finitely often, so it holds for all *interesting* sequences of good rational approximations.